# Backup a local database and restore to remote server using single command

Tags: php, mysql, vpn, database-replication, openvpn

I [read](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/) this article now.

I need to get the central database backup and restore it to the remote servers.

In this case I have 43 other branches servers and a central server.

That means i'm going to keep 44 database in my central server (Going to use a VPS).

So can I write a PHP script, to run the equivalent of the following command line code, to backup my branch servers to the central server?

So that I would have 43 databases on my central server to restore with 43 remote servers.
(I don't have a network connection to all 43 branche servers or doesn't have a VPN )

```
[local-server]# mysqldump -u root -ptmppassword sugarcrm | mysql \
                 -u root -ptmppassword --host=remote-server -C sugarcrm1
[Note: There are two -- (hyphen) in front of host]
```

Comment: if you have no network connection how you plan to do it?

Comment: So i need to connect it using VPN or OPENVPN.can't we have it over the internet ? i think it's not secure ?

Comment: my question is : is this code is ok ? and can we create a php script to run it over 43 branches ?

Comment: your shell dump and piping it to a mysql client has no issues. But i recommend finish one thing and do the next. If the connection interrupts you loose all the IO time you spent on creating the dump.

Comment: What about using [MySQL master/slave replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication.html)?

Comment: @MarkBaker  can we have 43 slaves ? and one master as central server ? Does it need a branch network ?

Comment: @Samitha - no reason why you can't have 1 master and 43 slaves

Comment: @MarkBaker   We have a 43 branches in our university.we just have a central server.if our internet interrupt we are using localhost to connect to the webapp.when the network is ok we need to send(localhost) data to our central server . is that possible with  MySQL master/slave replication

Comment: @DevZer0 see my above comment

Comment: @Samitha - why not read the link I posted, and the [replication FAQ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/faqs-replication.html)

Comment: A solution to this is VERY dependant upon how your application actually works and could only be completely answered with a complete understanding of how the application works.

Comment: Why do you need to move it to PHP?  Unless SSL is enabled across the MySQL connection (which it doesn't look like it is), I'd recommend piping it over an ssh tunnel.  You can still call this command from PHP using backticks or `shell_exec()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to think about using mysql replication (with 1 master and 43 slaves), instead of backing up and restoring periodically like you are describing here.  Replication would run continuously, so the 43 slaves would be synced to the master in real time.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-howto.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I would build a script that checks the connection first then if all ok, does the transfer. Once this script is tested you can call it once for each of your 43 databases. Some may fail, but your script will tell you which (if it reports errors properly). Then work out what is causing any failures. Eventually you will get all 43 going.

The backup script you end up with will use the code you have posted, but it will be more general and will have checking and reporting. Why don't you post it here when you have it working?

Greg Ambrose